# preg_replace only substring before defined char

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace chars not `[A-Z]` and before the `@` inside a string. So this

```
AreplacehereZ@domain.tld
```

needs to become:

```
A***********Z@domain.tld
```

I tried with:

```
$string = 'AreplacehereZ@domain.tld';
$pattern = '/(?<!@)[^A-Z@\.]/';
$replacement = '*';

$replace = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tring);
```

but the result is

```
'A***********Z@d*****.***'
```

So I can't find the way how to avoid the replacement of `@domain.tld` by only using `preg_replace()`.

`domain.tld` can be anything so I can't use `(?<!@domain.tld)` in the `$pattern` var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just assert that from the current position, match `[^A-Z]`, then make sure you can consume any number of characters but still hit the `@`:

```
$pattern = '/[^A-Z](?=[^@]*@)/';
```

[Produces](http://3v4l.org/kpdrj):

```
A***********Z@domain.tld
```